# Paint particles from texture

Tags: particles

I have black-white image which I use to generate particles and now I want to make particle colors similar to the original image (3). So in the end where should be some particles in color blue, some in green etc.. Is it possible to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but only using the Blender Internal renderer.

(Cycles doesn't render halos, and when rendering particles as an object, the particles take on the material of the original mesh, rather than the material of the emitter.)

That being said, this is how you can do it with the BI renderer:

Add a new material to the emitter, set its type to Halo and its colour to black

[image]

Go to the texture panel and add the texture as appropriate (Including the mapping)

[image]

Set its blending to add

[image]

Set the appropriate material slot in the particle system's properties.

[image]

Admire the beauty, because yours will probably be prettier than mine:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in cycles also, when using the UV coordinate texture node, make sure to click 'from dupli'[image: example using checkerboard]

Comment: Ty, this is nice. But in Cycles render i dont see where to add particle mask anymore. It's not possible?

Comment: 2.71 added UVnode which can be used the same way as texture coordinate (it also has 'from Dupli' option). However the described functionality is broken in official 2.71, it works again in the daily builds (I tried blender-2.71-1ff83d8-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2 from 2014-09-07)