# How to dissolve into particles a moving person on a RGBA video footage (using BI)

Tags: particles, blender-internal-render-engine, video

I have a slow pc with no GPU, and I want to know the **best way to dissolve into particles a moving person on a RGBA video footage (using BI).** Take into account that a **wind** simulator should be used with a wipe blend texture to trigger gradually the effect of this gone with the wind dude.

By best way I mean nice **performance** on slow pc.
**Low RAM and disk consumption**. Nice look n feel, each particle has to carry the color of the position it had on the victim person.

I made some other related questions before but I give up my current approach. At the moment my attempts were visually successful but render times went to hell and blender became very unusable while editing the scene so I lost control over the quality and the animation of my physics.

High ammount of subsurf levels and particle number are no good. Theorethically using less subsurf, less particle number and raise the children or trail ammount and use something like billboards may do but I can't reach that glory yet.

I have a Core2Duo with 5GB RAM using Win8 or Lubuntu. Blender 2.70.

Hope you can help!

Here is an example of what I'm looking to achieve in the animation:
[image: Sandstorm-like particle disolve example]

Comment: Use the explode modifier...

Comment: Already using it.

Comment: Can you provide a few example images please?

Comment: Sure @Samoth!, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkvLMjqA4_0)  is the effect I want to achieve solved in photoshop (1 frame)

Just watch until the final result appears (0:12)

Comment: One way of achieveing sort of this effect could be to add several particle systems, add (probably) several Smoke modifiers with particle systems set as flow source and partially mask the main mesh (character) which emits those particles and smoke. Also I believe that you won't be able to achieve such 3D effect without executing *a lot of* calculations (especially when testing).

Comment: Thnx @MrZak!, never used smoke mod before, mmm if you mind, can you elaborate a documented answer on how to do it? 

And what about using renderlayers to distribute cpu load (1 layer / particle system)? 

Or particle system cache?

Comment: Relevant question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/paint-particles-from-texture

Comment: I will try to add the answer further on when I finish my current projects and if I manage to create well-looking version of this one. You can use renderlayers combined with transparency to distribute complex scene rendering but it will be just several layers, which in sum will take the same quite big amount of time to render.

Comment: I guess one could treat this effect as a 1000000 non-shaded tiny halo particles with ~7 trail, with density and color, defined by images (I used alpha channel here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pr0gj.png) + bigger shaded gray group particles + smoke + dof + motion blur. Pretty broad question to answer.

Comment: @MrZak you are right, but maybe more render time can be better than an unresponsive iu. Hope you can elaborate the smoke mod answer! thanks for caring.

Comment: @Lockal Your approach is very interesting, generating the particles based on the video colors and not just exploding a whole subsurfed plane with an RGBA texture on it (my previous approach). The answer, even a basic one, would be a trending post I bet!