# How to scatter objects by texture?

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to scatter objects by texture(say, black and white texture like a checker map)? After scattering, the objects have to be instances and retain their original size and dimensions (without any deformations, squeezing you name it).
Thanks for helping me out.[image: I want the blue cone to scatter where the white dots are]

Comment: Maybe this is the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61918/trees-plants-rocks-spam-for-my-game-terrain/61923#61923 Add some screenshots of what you want to achieve or be more descriptive (with examples).

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/how-to-control-hair-particle-position (same for Emitter particle system type)

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot. Here's the deal guys: I want the blue cone to scatter exactly where the white dots are. Thanks for the links btw